# Play Morphia, Cannot grab List Content of (Generic) Embedded Object

Tags: playframework, morphia, playframework-1.x

I am working with Play Framework 1.2.5 and the morphia-1.2.9a module. I was originally using @Reference annotations on my models but due to the fact that (lazy=true) is not working on @Reference's, I needed to switch using ObjectIds. In an attempt to reduce rework and redundancies, I created the following MorphiaList:

```
package models.morphia;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;

import models.Team;

import org.bson.types.ObjectId;

import com.google.code.morphia.annotations.Embedded;
import com.google.code.morphia.annotations.Transient;

import play.modules.morphia.Model;
@Embedded
public class MorphiaList<T extends MorphiaModel> implements Iterable<T>{
    @Embedded("ids") private List<ObjectId> modelIds;
    @Transient List<T> models;
    public void sort()
    {
        this.getAll();
        Collections.sort(models);
        this.modelIds.clear();
        for(T t:this.models){
            this.modelIds.add((ObjectId)t.getId());
        }
    }
    public MorphiaList()
    {
        this.models = new ArrayList<T>();
        this.modelIds = new ArrayList<ObjectId>();
    }
    public int size()
    {
        System.out.println(modelIds.size());
        return modelIds.size();
    }
    public boolean add(T model)
    {
        return (this.models.add(model) && this.modelIds.add((ObjectId) model.getId()));
    }
    public boolean remove(T model)
    {
        return (this.models.remove(model)&&this.modelIds.remove((ObjectId) model.getId()));
    }
    public boolean addAll(Collection<? extends T> models)
    {
        for(T model: models)
        {
            this.models.add(model);
            this.modelIds.add((ObjectId) model.getId());
        }
        return false;
    }
    public List<T> getAll()
    {
        for(ObjectId oi: this.modelIds)
        {
            boolean found=false;
            for(T model: models)
            {
                if(oi==model.getId())
                {
                    found=true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if(!found)
                models.add(T.<T>findById(oi));
        }
        return models;
    }
    public T get(int index)
    {
        ObjectId id = modelIds.get(index);
        for(T model: models)
        {
            if(id == model.getId())
                return model;
        }
        return T.<T>findById(id);
    }
    @Override
    public Iterator<T> iterator() {
        return this.getModelIterator();
    }
    public Iterator<T> getModelIterator() {
        for(ObjectId oi: modelIds)
        {
            boolean found=false;
            for(T model: models)
            {
                if(oi==model.getId())
                {
                    found=true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if(!found)
                models.add(T.<T>findById(oi));
        }
        return models.iterator();
    }
    public boolean isEmpty() {
        return this.modelIds.isEmpty();
    }
    public boolean contains(T t) {
        return this.modelIds.contains(t.getId());
    }
}
```

MorphiaModel is simple, I just needed it to implement Comparable so I could sort my lists:

```
package models.morphia;
import play.modules.morphia.Model;
public abstract class MorphiaModel<T extends MorphiaModel<T>> extends Model implements Comparable<T>{
}
```

Then I use it like this in my classes:

```
@Entity
public class Organization extends Purchasable { 
@Embedded public MorphiaList<Season> seasons = new MorphiaList<Season>();
```

Once I add a season, mongo shows the expected:

```
{ 
 "_id" : { "$oid" : "50097c147aa33c43fa8136ee"} ,
 ...other members...
 "seasons" : { "ids" : [ { "$oid" : "50097c147aa33c43fa8136ed"}]} ,
 ...other members...
}
```

When I go to grab the seasons object though, modelIds is empty! I'm not sure why it can't grab seasons from the BSON, it's obviously there. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not get this to work for multiple reasons:

1. I could not get the data once persisted to the mongoDB to load back into the object, the object would always just be null.
2. After issue #1, I added a private list that would populate my MorphiaList on lookup to get around it. But after getting the ids into the MorphiaList, I could not figure out how to do a lookup on the specific collections. Especially when you consider I use inheritance so I have some heterogeneous collections.

My Solution: For every List of references I rewrote this:

```
@Reference public List<Season> seasons;
```

To this:

```
@Transient public List<Season> seasons;
private List<ObjectId> _seasons = new ArrayList();
@Transient private List<Season> pSeasons;
public List<Season> getSeasons()
{
    if(pSeasons==null)
    {
        if(_seasons.size()!=0)
            pSeasons = Season.find().<Season>field("_id").in(_seasons).asList();
        else
            pSeasons = new ArrayList();
    }
    return pSeasons;
}
```

I also had to add a **@PrePersist** method to check for list access:

```
@PrePersist void beforeSave()
{
    if(pSeasons!=null)
    {
        _seasons.clear();
        for(Season s: pSeasons)
        {
            _seasons.add((ObjectId)s.getId());
        }
    }
}
```

This **beforeSave()** will have to expand for every extra List of refs you have in your code. Moral of the story:

*If you're using Play's morphia module, don't use the @Reference notation.*